# Magnetostatics of Current-Carrying wire

Tags: maxwell-equations, classical-electrodynamics

A question has been nagging at me about Faraday's Law as related to a wire with a constant current:

If you have a circular loop of wire with some small resistivity, connected to a battery so that it has a constant DC current, the electric field inside the wire is going to be longitudinal and proportional to the current density. In particular, is going to be something like $\vec{E}=E_0\hat{\phi}$, choosing cylindrical coordinates with the origin at the center of the loop. The curl of this field is obviously nonzero, so applying Faraday's Law there should be a linearly growing magnetic field in the Z direction, at every point inside the wire. But this seems like nonsense; we're supposed to be in a steady-state, and it doesn't seem physically plausible to me that there is a field that can be growing arbitrarily large as we keep our battery plugged in, or that its growth should be affected by the shape of the wire loop. So I expect I am missing some contribution that would cancel this effect. But what it is? I feel like I must be missing something obvious, but can't for the life of me see what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply Faraday's law here, the net emf around the loop is zero (as expected). You forget that there is a battery in the loop, which has a large, opposite electric field across it. So $\varepsilon=\varepsilon_{loop}+\varepsilon_{battery}=0$. Which means that $-\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}=0$, so $B=constant$, which means that the loop on its own will not induce any magnetic field, but it can survive in a system with a constant magnetic field without any change.

Comment: You are certainly correct that the total magnetic flux is zero, but this doesn't quite resolve my question. Applying the differential form of Faraday's law to the battery in the same way as I did to the wire above, it seems to me that one would get a time-changing magnetic field in each, such that their contributions to the path integral cancel each other out. A continuously increasing magnetic field in the battery, whose total flux is opposite that of the continuously increasing field in the wire, still seems physically suspect to me.

Comment: @Rococo: How are you using the differential form? You don't know what the electric field inside the loop looks like. You have assumes the electric field on the wire to have some value, but you need to know what it looks like in the near neighborhood to be able to calculate a curl. The differential and integral forms are consistent, if the integral form gives an answer, the differential form will too.

Comment: Hi Manishearth, I was applying Ohm's Law, in the form
$\vec{J}=\sigma\vec{E}$. In this case, assuming that the current density in the wire is uniform, the electric field also will be.

Comment: @Rococo: That's only in the wire. (a) you can't assume that $\vec J$ is uniform, it may vary as you move radially outwards on the wire. (b) If you're taking a thin wire, you still need to know $\vec E$ outside.

Comment: @Rococo: I gues the best way to explain this is to consider the fringing fields on the battery as well. These will most likely set the curl back to zero.

Comment: I don't really see how fringing fields could be relevant. We know that the electric field overall has to follow the path of the wire, or we are no longer in a steady current state (because electrons will smack into the wire edges). Likewise, even if $\vec{J}$ is nonuniform, as long as it is purely in the azimuthal direction I don't think this changes the analysis. I think I'm going to look for opinions on other boards, thanks for the input though...

Comment: @Rococo When dealing with stuff like this, fringe fields are _the_ reason for such apparent discrepancies in such situations with batteries or capacitors.. A purely azimuthal $\vec J$  means _nothing_, I can still construct one with zero curl.

Simple fact: Stoke's theorem holds here. If the integral form of Maxwell's equation works out, so does the differential form.

Comment: Hm, well if you can provide an example of a vector field that would take an electron around a closed path but has a nonzero curl, I'd consider this question resolved. I was not able to construct one, but perhaps this is a limit on my imagination.

I am not satisfied with your point about the integral form because the integral form of the equation, although logically equivalent, answers a somewhat different question. (to be continued)

Comment: It is analogous to if I were asking what the electric field was from an electric dipole. In that case, you could use the integral form of Gauss' Law to say that the total electric flux from the dipole must be zero, but it does not follow that the electric field is zero at any point. Likewise, in this case you are obviously correct in saying that the total magnetic flux is zero, but this does not answer my question about the magnetic field at a given point. Nonetheless, thank you for your responses.

Comment: @Rococo: The field _doesn't_ take an electron along a closed path. There's an opposite field in the battery (which fringes outside), and the electrons stop at the plates. You may be right about the nonzero curl, though I'm not too certain. The electric field of this situation is more like a dipole and not really a loop (replace the battery with a capacitor and this becomes obvious). IMO, taking smaller patches will still give zero emf/zero flux (if this applies everywhere, then the B field is constant).

Comment: However, IIRC the field inside a battery is not an electrostatic field and shall have a nonzero curl. But this is only inside the battery. (and the energy for this is extracted from the battery and isn't much)

Comment: Ah! Your analogy to a dipole made it click for me. You're right- a clear way to think about this is a dipole field, modified by the induced surface charges on the wire that 'steer' the current.

Comment: @Rococo: Yep ,exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, the self-inductance of any closed loop like this *inhibits* current flow; it doesn't swell it infinitely. That's back-emf. Second, while the total magnetic field of the loop will be in the $Z$ direction *at the origin*, it won't be so in the wires. Remember that the magnetic field of any small section of current-carrying wire is a [cylinder](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magcur.html). The sum of all these little contributions is what gives us the total field that you described, which looks like [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html).

So, summing up, when the circuit is first connected, self-inductance in the wires themselves and in the loop as a whole prevent the current from reaching its final state instantaneously, and the resistance of the wire and the internal resistance of the battery cause the current to reach equilibrium at its steady state. At that point, the loop has a steady magnetic field, but doesn't have to worry about self-inductance anymore.

I may have misunderstood you question, but I think that will help.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with self-inductance. Basically I am asking how an electric field that is clearly physically curving, due to the influence of a wire, avoids creating a magnetic field.

Comment: oops, sorry about that then. I thought I was missing something.